# How can i keep background android services running when app killed or closed

Tags: android, kotlin, android-service

**Hello guys**

I have News app, I want to push notification every updates.

I use socketIO to make listen from the server,
My problem with Android Services I want to keep Service running while up closed | killed.
I have start my services when app running and I return in onStartCommand  START_STICKY_COMPATIBILITY
its work correctly when app close but while of hour services killed by OS but not start again
any help ?


**Note:**  I ignore battery optimize for the app

My Services Class:

```
class ServicesMain: Service() {
    override fun onBind(p0: Intent?): IBinder? {
       return  null;
    }
    @SuppressLint("TrulyRandom")
    fun handleSSLHandshake() {
        try {
            val trustAllCerts = arrayOf<TrustManager>(object : X509TrustManager {
                override fun getAcceptedIssuers(): Array<X509Certificate>? {
                    return null;
                }

                override fun checkClientTrusted(certs: Array<X509Certificate>, authType: String) {}
                override fun checkServerTrusted(certs: Array<X509Certificate>, authType: String) {}
            })
            val sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL")
            sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, SecureRandom())
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.socketFactory)
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier { arg0, arg1 -> true }
        } catch (ignored: Exception) {
        }
    }
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
fun  startSocket(){
    handleSSLHandshake()
    runBroadcast()
    Log.d("TAG", "BroadcastReceiver: ")
    Timer().schedule(object : TimerTask() {
        override fun run() {
            Log.d("TAG", "run: ${socket!!.connected()} ")

        }

    }, 0, 10000)



}
    private var socket: Socket? = null;

    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    fun runBroadcast() {
        val myHostnameVerifier = HostnameVerifier { _, _ ->
            return@HostnameVerifier true
        }

        val trustAllCerts = arrayOf<TrustManager>(object : X509TrustManager {
            override fun checkClientTrusted(chain: Array<X509Certificate>, authType: String) {}

            override fun checkServerTrusted(chain: Array<X509Certificate>, authType: String) {}

            override fun getAcceptedIssuers(): Array<X509Certificate> {
                return arrayOf()
            }
        })

        val sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS")
        sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, null)

        val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .hostnameVerifier(myHostnameVerifier)
                .sslSocketFactory(sslContext.socketFactory, trustAllCerts[0] as X509TrustManager)
                .readTimeout(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).writeTimeout(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).build()

        val options = IO.Options()
        options.transports = arrayOf(Polling.NAME)
        options.webSocketFactory = okHttpClient
        options.callFactory=okHttpClient
        options.secure = true
        socket = IO.socket("https://....", options);

        socket!!.connect().on("message", Emitter.Listener { args ->


            val jsonObject = JSONObject(args[0] as String)

            val calendarTime = jsonObject.getLong("starttime") - (Calendar.getInstance().timeInMillis)

            println(calendarTime)

            val builder = Constraints.Builder()
                    .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
            val data: Data.Builder = Data.Builder()
            data.putStringArray("data", arrayOf<String>(jsonObject.getString("title"), jsonObject.getString("subject"), jsonObject.getString("id")))


            val oneTimeWorkRequest = OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(NotificationEvetns::class.java).setInputData(data.build()).setConstraints(builder.build())
                    .setInitialDelay(calendarTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).addTag(jsonObject.getString("id")).build()
            this.let { WorkManager.getInstance(it).enqueue(oneTimeWorkRequest) }
        })


}

    override fun onTaskRemoved(rootIntent: Intent?) {

        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent)
        Log.d("TAG", "onTaskRemoved: ")
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        Log.d("TAG", "onStartCommand: ")

        return  START_STICKY_COMPATIBILITY
    }




    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        startSocket()
    }


    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        socket?.disconnect()
    }

    override fun onTrimMemory(level: Int) {
        super.onTrimMemory(level)
        Log.d("TAG", "onTrimMemory: ")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, not on modern versions of Android.  You can make a foreground service which is the least likely thing to be killed (outside of the foreground app), but you can't count on it not being killed.  Instead write your code so that it doesn't need to-  mainly by using WorkManager for triggered background work.  Unless you're writing a server, in which case I'd say that you should use another OS, Android isn't suitable.

For messages from a server like you mentioned, I'd use FCM push messaging rather than a long lived direct server connection.

Comment: WorkManager  for pushing notification when notification will start 
about foreground  how can i start it without showing notification ?

Comment: @JawadFadel You can't.  The reason they added that was to stop apps from running in the background without users knowing.  Really what you're trying to do is everything Android is trying to stop you from doing.